# SQL Server EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords() powershell method connecting to wrong instance of SQL Server

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server named instance that runs the standard **syspolicy_purge_history** job every night.  The job is marked as succeeding every night, but every night on the DEFAULT instance on the same server, there is a failed login connection from the service account of the named instance.

I've tracked it down to the **Erase Phantom System Health Records** step of the syspolicy_purge_history job.  The job uses the standard code and does not appear to have been modified in any way:

```
if ('$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(INST))' -eq 'MSSQLSERVER') {$a = '\DEFAULT'} ELSE {$a = ''};
(Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))$a).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

There are two other named instances on the same server, running the same job with the same code, and they do not generate failed login errors on the default instance.

I tried deleting the job, and recreating it by scripting the job from one of the other named instances.  It made no difference.

I tried changing the code of step 3 to:

```
(Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\[MyServerName]\[NamedInstanceName]).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

and alternatively to:

```
(Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\[MyServerName]\[NamedInstanceName]`,[NamedInstancePort]).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

Both versions still generate the failed login on the default instance.

Both versions of the command appear to work successfully if I run them from a powershell window, and do NOT generate a failed login.

I cannot think of anything else to try.  Google seems to be out of suggestions for me too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/sql-server-login-failure-every-day-at-same-time-with-the-service-account

Comment: Yeah that looks like it.  Good find!